# Playing audio using discord bot - discordjs 14

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, VoiceConnectionStatus, createAudioResource } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { join } = require('path'); // Dovresti usare 'path' invece di 'node:path'

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('play')
    .setDescription('Playing audio in a voice channel'),
  async execute(interaction) {
    // Verifica se l'utente è in un canale vocale
    if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) {
      await interaction.reply('Devi essere in un canale vocale per utilizzare questo comando.');
      return;
    }

    // Connetti il bot al canale vocale
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: interaction.member.voice.channelId,
      guildId: interaction.guildId,
      adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });

    connection.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(`Errore nella connessione al canale vocale: ${error.message}`);
    });
    
    // Gestisci lo stato della connessione
    connection.on(VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, () => {
      const player = createAudioPlayer();
      const resource = createAudioResource(join(__dirname, '../../img/push-push.mp3'));

      player.play(resource);

      // Connetti il player alla connessione vocale
      connection.subscribe(player);
    });

    
  },
};
```

i have this slashcommand for send and playing audio in a channelvoice discord by my bot.
My bot sent audio but is not possible to stop it

I would like the file to be played but with the possibility of pausing or stopping it